# C++: How can I print unicode characters to text file

Tags: c++, string, file, unicode

I need to print unicode symbols to the file, but I get their codes instead.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int code = 33;
    wchar_t sym = wchar_t(code);

    ofstream output ("output.txt");
    output << sym << "\n";
    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```

So I expect to see `!` in my file, but I see `33`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using wofstream ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/wofstream/

Comment: Yes, use `std::wofstream` instead.  And FYI, cplusplus.com is generally considered to be a poor C++ reference site, you should use cppreference.com ([wofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream))

Comment: Do you want UTF-8 or UTF-16? And do you want BOM at the start of the file. And does your viewer open the file in the proper format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::ofstream` operates on `char` data and does not have any `operator<<` that takes `wchar_t` data as input.  It does have `operator<<` that takes `int`, and `wchar_t` is implicitly convertible to `int`.  That is why you are getting the character outputted as a number.

You need to use [`std::wofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) instead for `wchar_t` data.

Comment: @igor_bal how the `wchar_t` data is encoded depends on the locale that is `imbue()`'d into the stream

Answer (score 1):

> How can I print unicode characters to text file
>
> I expect to see ! in my file

Here is an example writing

UTF-8:

```
std::ofstream output("output.txt");
output << u8"!\n";
```

UTF-16:

```
std::basic_ofstream<char16_t> output ("output.txt");
output << u"!\n";
```

UTF-32:

```
std::basic_ofstream<char32_t> output ("output.txt");
output << U"!\n";
```

`wchar_t` may also work, but only when the wide compilation character encoding is unicode. Whether it is UTF-16 or UTF-32 or something else depends on the system:

```
std::wofstream output ("output.txt");
output << L"!\n";
```